Why are political donations public?
All political donations over $200 are public in the United States.
Why is this? $200 does not seem like enough to place a political candidate significantly in debt to an individual donor. It seems odd that one's vote is required by law to be secret, but one's donations are required by law to be public.

Just to point out that while your actual vote is secret, that fact that you voted is public record.

The purpose of these laws, for the most part, is to prevent one group or individual from funneling massive amounts of money into a campaign, effectively 'buying' a candidate. I could debate how well this works in practice — there are better ways to deal with this problem — but that's the principle involved.
One of the tricks that people have used to get around this restriction is to divide a large sum of money up between a large group of people, all of whom make individual contributions. For instance, a wealthy business owner could funnel three million dollars to a candidate by paying a thousand people to give the 3,300 maximum individual donation. The key to stopping this kind of malfeasance is to make donations public, so that relationships can be traced between donors and back to any source. $200 in 1971 was equivalent to about $1,500 today, so still a sizable donation (yeah, inflation!). But it's a small enough amount that it would require an extremely large number of people to make any significant illicit donation (about 15,000 people for the same three million dollar figure). It's an arbitrary small number, yes, but the intention is to make crowd-sourcing illicit donations impractical.

Part of the reason that it doesn't work well in practice is that there are ways to get around the requirement to disclose donors either by delaying releasing the information or preventing releasing it at all based on how/who you donate to.

Has the $200 limit not been raised since 1971? IMO, it'd be kind of ridiculous for the dollar value of ANYTHING to not have been raised since 1971.

@VeryTinyBrain The US government is very bad at updating laws with monetary amounts due to inflation. Look at the federal minimum wage -- it kept pace with inflation until 1968, but it would be around $25 now if it continued. One of the few things that automatic increases every year is the maximum IRA contribution.

The way rich donors get around this now is Super PACs. Contributions to PACs don't have to be disclosed.

@Barmar that this loophole exists is ... sad.

Yes. Two words: Citizens United. Another two words: Supreme Court @Edheldil

The funneling sounds reasonable enough, but lacks sourcing indicating this was actually a problem.  For example, if a rich businessman gave $3M to 1000 people, in a context of anonymous donations, what makes you think a sizable proportion of those people wouldn't just pocket the $3000, without donating anything?  If anything, this behavior is exactly what unions attempt to engage in which is why some countries ban both union and corporate donations.

@Barmar: about a hundred amounts in the tax code (26USC) are updated yearly -- for 2024 in Revenue Procedure 2023-34 and Notice 2023-75 both in Nov 2023. But the update doesn't produce an increase when inflation isn't enough to move to the next rounded value; this has occurred in many years for IRA, and more for (smaller) IRA-catchup. (Employer plans have a higher limit rarely if ever masked by rounding, and similarly the standard deductions and taxable-income brackets. OTOH TCJA's $10k limit on itemized SALT is NOT adjusted, to punish 'blue' states.)

@ItalianPhilosopher Giving people money isn't part of the scheme - the puppets never come in contact with the money. They sign the paperwork for an account in their name, give it to their handler, the handler does the rest.

@dave_thompson_085 About a hundred? Out of how many? I also suspect there's more indexing in tax code than other monetary legislation because it affects most constituents. But WIC and social security are also indexed ot inflation.

This was put in place by S 382 - Federal Election Campaign Act of 1971.
S.382's contemporary campaign would be the best place to check out the motivations for the individual donor reporting limits.  But note that the original law has been altered and that its initial motivations were broader than just reporting, including placing limits on the amount and nature of contributions.

S. 382 (92nd): An Act to promote fair practices in the conduct of election campaigns for Federal political offices, and for other purposes

The Federal Election Campaign Act of 1971 (FECA, Pub.L. 92–225, 86 Stat. 3, enacted February 7, 1972, 52 U.S.C. § 30101 et seq.) is the primary United States federal law regulating political campaign spending and fundraising. The law originally focused on increased disclosure of contributions for federal campaigns. The S. 382 legislation was passed by the 92nd U.S. Congressional session and signed by the 37th President of the United States Richard Nixon on February 7, 1972.


In addition to limiting the size of contributions to candidates and political parties, FECA also requires campaigns and political committees to report the names, addresses, and occupations of donors of more than $200.

This in turn has a wikipedia Federal Election Campaign Act which gives some background, including the fact that Nixon vetoed a preceding attempt to pass such a law.

As early as 1905, Theodore Roosevelt argued in favor of campaign finance reform and called for a ban of corporate contributions for political purposes. In response, the United States Congress passed the Tillman Act of 1907, which banned the corporate contributions. Further regulation followed in the Federal Corrupt Practices Act enacted in 1910, and subsequent amendments in 1910 and 1925, the Hatch Act, the Smith–Connally Act of 1943, and the Taft–Hartley Act in 1947. These acts sought to regulate corporate and union spending in campaigns for federal office, and mandated public disclosure of campaign donors.

Given that the Canadian limits are also $200, I am curious if the Canadian law predated the US one or was inspired by it.

The tradition is far longer though. Covertly giving money to politicians was described as tantamount to corruption since some SCOTUS decision in the 1850s. And the first laws came about in FDR's time IIRC.

The full original text talks about tracking even lower amounts, $50, but it's unclear if those would have been publicly disclosed as asked about here.

In addition to the answer from Ted Wrigley which is correct as far as it goes, it also allows for other kinds of analysis, such as examinations of which disbursed groups, like teachers or finance professionals or oil and gas industry workers favor a candidate. And, it is important in evaluation potential bias from judges or other decision-makers on partisan matters (e.g. election related lawsuits).
